# Composer REST Server で、Githubを使用したOAuth認証ができない

Tags: oauth

■質問内容

以下のサイトを参考に、Composer REST Server にて、PassportとGithubを使用したOAuth認証を有効化させようとしています。
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication
一通り手順通りに進めているのですが、外部端末のブラウザで「http://≪ホスト≫:3000/auth/github」開くと、404のエラーとなります。
上記公式の説明によればOAuthのWebサーバーにリダイレクトされるようですが、そうなりません。
設定の誤りや漏れがありましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

■操作内容
下記URLの操作です。
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication
「Authenticating to the REST server using a web browser」におけるURLを開く操作には、外部端末（Windows10/Chrome/Cookieは有効化してある）を使用しています。
そのため、URLのlocalhost部分はドメインに読み替えています。

■確認できていること

外部端末のブラウザで「http://≪ホスト≫:3000/」を開いた際は、問題なく「http://≪ホスト≫:3000/explorer」へリダイレクトされ、APIを試すことができます。

「Hyperledger Composer REST Server」にて適当なメソッドを実行すると、意図通り401のエラー（Authorization Required）となります。
このエラーはOAuthを設定せずにREST Serverを操作した際には出ないものなので、OAuth認証の設定自体はある程度有効になっていると考えています。

■環境・設定内容

・サーバーの端末と開放ポート
Azureに立てた仮想マシンを使用しています。
3000番/443番/80番のポートは、IN/OUT共に開放しています。

・OS
Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS

・~/.profileに設定した環境変数（設定後に「source ~/.profile」で再読込済）
[image: 環境変数]

・インストールしてあるnpmパッケージ
[image: インストールしてあるnpmパッケージ]

・その他Composer関連のパッケージのバージョン
[image: その他Composer関連のパッケージのバージョン]

・Github側の設定内容
[image: Github側の設定内容]